# Identification of a fantasy/mystery book about a sentient tree

Tags: story-identification

Story is of a family that moves to a house with a tree in the yard. They start having strange dreams. Touching the tree causes a trance state. They find out the previous home owner died from cutting off his leg with a chainsaw (the tree was protecting itself). In the end the people do a kind of mind-meld with the tree... That's all I remember. Anyone know the title?

Comment: What do you mean by story? Was it a short story? Novel? Graphic novel? When did you read this story? Do you recall the cover art?

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like Piers Anthony's [Shade of the Tree](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15471.Shade_of_the_Tree)

> The estate was Joshua Pinson's inheritance from his oddball uncle Elijah: isolated in the deep Florida woods, with a half-built solar house stocked with enough supplies to weather a siege. Josh decided it was time to take his two young children away from New York and the memories of their murdered mother. Time to make a new life in sunny Florida. There was just one thing that Josh hadn't counted on.
>
> The place was haunted.

[image: Book cover - Shade of the Tree]

Comment: Yes, this sounds like it. The protagonist is called Josh and he inherited the house from his Uncle Elijah. Elijah died of blood loss after cutting his leg with a chain saw while trying to cut down the tree. Josh ends up sharing his consciouness with the tree.

Comment: Confirmed, although the tree wasn't sentient. It did, however, have the instinctive ability to protect itself by projecting visions.